# How can deploy custom SQL-based reports to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online , If Can't How can change SQL-based reports to FetchXML Reports?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

How can deploy custom SQL-based reports to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online , If Can't How can change SQL-based reports to FetchXML Reports ?

I made Report rdl SQL-based (Advanced Query) and when to attach it on MS CRM 2013 Online , it can't upload it , because it supports FetchXML only , so if can change my SQL-based report rdl to FetchXML Report.

Comment: I made Report rdl SQL-based (Advanced Query) and when to attach it on MS CRM 2013 Online , it can't upload it , because it supports FetchXML only , so if can change my SQL-based report rdl to FetchXML Report .

Answer (score 2):

Dynamics CRM Online supports only FetchXML reports.

If you have SQL-based reports you need to convert them to use FetchXML instead of SQL queries.

You can try also this service to help you with the conversion

http://sql2fetchxml.com/